# Parsing error: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am importing CSS from my App.css and i am getting the error:

> Parsing error: Invalid or unexpected token

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classes from "../../App.css";
import "../../App.css";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Aux";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Aux>
    <p>hello from navbar</p>
    <div className={classes.navbar-1}>
      <div className={classes.navbar-1__margin}></div>
    </div>
  </Aux>
  )
  }
}
```

[image]

what's the problem?

Comment: Instead of `classes.navbar-1__margin` try `classes['navbar-1__margin']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import classes from "../../App.css";
import "../../App.css";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Aux";
export default class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Aux>
    <p>hello from navbar</p>
    <div className={classes['navbar-1']}>
      <div className={classes['navbar-1__margin']}></div>
    </div>
  </Aux>
  )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just import and use classes directly, like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../../App.css";
import Aux from "../../hoc/Aux";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <Aux>
      <p>hello from navbar</p>
      <div className="navbar-1">
        <div className="navbar-1__margin"></div>
      </div>
    </Aux>
  )
  }
}
```